# Windows batch file to delete all files on desktop

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm looking to write a batch file that will remove all files on my computers desktop except for folders and .lnk (shortcut files)

The reason being that I want to run this batch file to remove all files on our meeting room PC so it's kept nice and tidy.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a code writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and we churn out the code for you. We expect you to have made at least a sincere effort to find a solution yourself, including searching this site (and Google) for possible solutions. You've shown no indication of having done so. Good luck.

Comment: From the command line, you can get a list of all non-directories and non-lnk files with this command:  `dir /b /a-D | findstr /v "\.lnk$"`

Comment: @indiv is not necessary to filter the output, you can go directly with FOR/FORFILES.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Echo OFF

For %%# in (
    "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\*"
) Do (
    If /I not "%%~x#" EQU ".lnk" (
        Del /Q "%%#"
    )
)

Pause&Exit
```

Comment: You can use the `/i` case insensitive switch in the `if` command.  It really needs to deal with the all users profile too.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Echo OFF

For /f "tokens=*" %%I in ('dir /s /b /a:-d-h  "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\*"') Do (
    call :delIfNotLnk "%%I"
)
goto :EOF

:delIfNotLnk 
if  not "%~x1" == ".lnk" (
        Del /Q %1
)
goto :EOF
```